# How to an ElasticSearch snapshot in Node js?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Environment description :

- ElasticSearch : v1.4.3
- NodeJS : v0.12.7

I would like to do a snapshot of ElasticSearch cluster with the nodeJs API.
I watch the API documentation but there isn't a single example so I don't even know how to write it. The only thing I have is the syntax :

```
client.snapshot.create([params, [callback]])
```

You can see the documentation here : [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-1-4.html#api-snapshot-create-1-4)

I try to do it with :

```
client.snapshot.create({"waitForCompletion":true, "snapshot":"snapshot_4", "repository":"my_backup"});
```

But it gives me this error :

```
Unhandled rejection Error: InvalidIndexNameException[[_snapshot] Invalid index name [_snapshot], must not start with '_']
at respond (D:\Users\ermaro\Documents\SG\kyc\trunk\kyc\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:256:15)
at checkRespForFailure (D:\Users\ermaro\Documents\SG\kyc\trunk\kyc\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:219:7)
at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (D:\Users\ermaro\Documents\SG\kyc\trunk\kyc\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\connectors\http.js:155:7)
at IncomingMessage.wrapper (D:\Users\ermaro\Documents\SG\kyc\trunk\kyc\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3095:19)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Is there anybody who ever try this and give an hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the git page of node.js for ES. A bug is logged for this. Reference:

> https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/170
>
> https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/pull/108